# C# TCP Tunnel sends lots of nulls

Tags: c#, tcp, mono, tunnel

I'm trying to write a simple TCP network tunnel in C# (with MonoDevelop, not VS). Currently, it works up to the point at which I make a connection. After connecting with `netcat localhost <portnum>`, I get packets filled with nulls sent at me constantly. My code is:

### `Tunnel.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class Tunnel {
    public TcpListener listener;
    public NetworkStream local, remote;
    private Thread threadControl, threadLocalSide, threadRemoteSide;
    public Tunnel(int localPort, String remoteServer, int remotePort) {
        this.listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 }), localPort));
        this.remote = new TcpClient(remoteServer, remotePort).GetStream();
        this.threadControl = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.thread));
        this.threadControl.Start();
    }
    public void thread() {
        this.listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Awaiting connection...");
        this.local = this.listener.AcceptTcpClient().GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine("Tunnel connected!");
        Console.WriteLine("Starting threads...");
        this.threadLocalSide = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.localSide));
        this.threadLocalSide.Start();
        this.threadRemoteSide = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.remoteSide));
        this.threadRemoteSide.Start();
    }
    public void localSide() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        try {
            while(true) {
                while(!this.local.DataAvailable);
                this.local.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                this.remote.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        } catch {
            this.threadRemoteSide.Abort();
        }
    }
    public void remoteSide() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        try {
            while(true) {
                while(!this.remote.DataAvailable);
                this.remote.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                this.local.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        } catch {
            this.threadLocalSide.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always check the return value of `this.remote.Read` and `this.local.Read`. It is wrong to assume that you will always read the data in one go.

Comment: [Read method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) You should use return value of `read` as @DanielKelley suggested

Comment: It is unclear that why do you abort `threadRemoteSide` in localSide and viceversa

Comment: If there's an exception in one thread, the other needs to die too. Having a two-way tunnel turn into a one-way is gonna be painful to debug.

Comment: It doesn't send any nulls. The nulls are already there in the receive buffer, and as you are ignoring the read count you are erroneously treating them as part of the received data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stream.Read()` method returns number of bytes actually received, but you are always sending the whole buffer.

Try to copy data from one stream to another this way:

```
static void CopyStream(Stream from, Stream to)
{
    var buffer = new byte[2048];
    while(true)
    {
        int bytesRead = from.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if(bytesRead == 0) break; // 0 means end of stream
        to.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}

localSide() { CopyStream(local, remote); }
remoteSide() { CopyStream(remote, local); }
```

Comment: OK, thanks! I'm rather new to networking outside of C (or C++ using the C libraries). Says 4 minutes left until I can accept...

Comment: return value `0` doesn't mean `end of stream`. It mean currently no data available

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: MSDN, remarks section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.90%29

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx#remarksToggle correct me if am wrong, Check remarks section

Comment: `NetworkStream.Read()` internally uses `Socket.Receive()`, which blocks until socket failed, closed or received something, so `0` return value should mean that no more data can be received.